# Python Windows path with escape character error

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path, escaping

I have a windows path stored in a variable called "a". When I tried to print or use it in the code, somehow some special characters are added to the string.

```
    >>> import re
    >>> from pathlib import Path 
    >>> 
    >>> 
    >>> a = "E:\POC\testing\functionalities\logs\timer.logs"
    >>> a
    'E:\\POC\testing\x0cunctionalities\\logs\timer.logs'
    >>>
    >>> Path(a)
    WindowsPath('E:/POC\testing\x0cunctionalities/logs\timer.logs')
    >>> Path.absolute(a)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1159, in absolute
        if self._closed:
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_closed'
    >>>                 
    >>> re.escape(a)
    'E:\\\\POC\\\testing\\\x0cunctionalities\\\\logs\\\timer\\.logs'
    >>>
    >>> a.replace("\\", "/")
    'E:/POC\testing\x0cunctionalities/logs\timer.logs'
    >>> a.__repr__()
    "'E:\\\\POC\\testing\\x0cunctionalities\\\\logs\\timer.logs'"
    >>>
```

I'm able to handle all the special characters but **\f is somehow changed to \x0c**.

One solution is adding **r** to the string, but my path is stored in a variable. How I can achieve that? I'm using python 3.8.5 and Windows 10

```
    >>> a = r"E:\POC\testing\functionalities\logs\timer.logs" 
    >>> a
    'E:\\POC\\testing\\functionalities\\logs\\timer.logs'
    >>>  
    >>> 
    >>> a = "E:\POC\testing\functionalities\logs\timer.logs"  
    >>> a = r"" + a
    >>> a
    'E:\\POC\testing\x0cunctionalities\\logs\timer.logs'
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use raw string or escape the backward slash:

```
a = r"E:\POC\testing\functionalities\logs\timer.logs"
```

or

```
a = "E:\\POC\\testing\\functionalities\\logs\\timer.logs"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do this, I'm getting the path in runtime. So basically it is stored in a variable. 
`a = "E:\POC\testing\functionalities\logs\timer.logs"` 
Imagine this path is stored in this variable. Now tell me How I can achieve the same above results for this variable "a"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment under @user8086906's post, couldn't you just do

```
a.replace('\\', '\')
```

? I see you tried `a.replace("\\", "/")` above - could you explain what the desired behavior is? On my machine, the first snippet I posted works.

EDIT:

Thanks @Gopirengaraj C - I see what the issue is now. The problem is that `\f` is an escape character in Unicode - more specifically, it is called a *"form feed"*. I think a good way to get around this would then be to avoid `replace` and do something like this instead:

```
a = r'{0}'.format(a)
```

Lmk if that works.

Comment: `'E:/POC\testing\x0cunctionalities/logs\timer.logs'` in this value of f in functionalities is changed to \x0c